# Is there a way to add a separator between XML data gathered from multiple identical tags using Powershell?

Tags: xml, rest, powershell, xml-parsing

I have recently started working for a new company and their prior tech created a Powershell script designed to pull XML data from the REST API of a cloud forms software. It pulls the relevant data from the API and turns it into a readable CSV of metadata to attach to a file imported by the ADI of an internal file management software we use. I understand how the script works and it has been doing just fine with prior forms. The issue is with a new form that is designed to have multiple entries in a single response. If multiple entries are added to this form the script does not carry the data into the CSV.

I am a Powershell novice and have no idea where I need to start to get this problem resolved.

I've attempted to remove all but the most pertinent portions of the XML to use as examples of what I'm working with which makes a pretty large change to the full XML structure. Here are 2 examples of XML Data:

1. Example of data that makes it to the CSV

```
<Submission Id="1">
  <Form Id="1">
    <Name>Example 1</Name>
  </Form>
  <Section>
    <Name>Projected Completion Dates</Name>
    <Responses>
      <Response Guid="30547A781493817AA0BDBE7C5C6F949A6292FC92">
        <Label>Projected Completion Dates</Label>
        <Value>04/08/2019</Value>
        <Type>Date</Type>
      </Response>
    </Responses>
  </Section>
</Submission>
```

2. Example of Data that does not make it to the CSV

```
<Submission Id="2">
  <Form Id="2">
    <Name>Example 2</Name>
  </Form>
  <Section>
    <Name>Completion Dates</Name>
    <Responses>
      <Responses Entry="Completion Dates">
        <Response Guid="5151F9FC73A03E31B971F38D42CD5300CD6F3C2F">
          <Label>Completion Dates</Label>
          <Value>04/19/2019</Value>
          <Type>Date</Type>
        </Response>
        <Response Guid="5151F9FC73A03E31B971F38D42CD5300CD6F3C2F">
          <Label>Completion Dates</Label>
          <Value>04/26/2019</Value>
          <Type>Date</Type>
        </Response>
      </Responses>
    </Responses>
  </Section>
</Submission>
```

I can provide the entire script if need be, but I will attempt to redact the Powershell code to what's relevant to the XML data parsing.

```
        #PARSE XML DATA TO OBJECT
        $responses = $parsedXML.SelectNodes("/CanvasResult/Submissions/Submission/Sections/Section/Screens/Screen/Responses/Response") 

        #CREATE OBJECT THAT MARRIES GOCANVAS XML DATA W/ FILEHOLD METADATA
        $objMarry = New-Object -TypeName PSObject

        #DYNAMICALLY MARRY LOCAL XML VALUES AND GOCAVNAS API VALUES
        foreach ($GCValue in $obj.value){

            $objMarry | Add-Member -Type noteProperty `
            -Name $GCValue `
            -Value ($responses | Where-Object {$_.Label -eq $GCValue} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value)
        }
```

While writing this up it dawned on me that the XML that is not working has a second `<Responses>` tag and that SelectNodes only covers for the first Responses tag. However, the second responses tag only occurs if there are multiple entries. So if I'm thinking about this right the issue here is how to adjust the code to look for the second Responses tag and gather that data as well to put in the CSV. My only thought is to add `$multiresponses = $parsedXML.SelectNodes("/CanvasResult/Submissions/Submission/Sections/Section/Screens/Screen/Responses` **/Responses** `/Response")` and use an if statement to check for null values and add `$multiresponses` entries there, but I do not know how to code the check for null entries let alone add the multiple entries and separate them with a _.

So, to summarize:

Expected Results:

Single Entry: data from XML is added to CSV (in example 1 XML above, entry would be 04/08/2019)

Multiple Entries: All XML entries are added to CSV and separated by a _ (in example 2 XML above, result would be 04/19/2019_04/26/2019)

Actual Results:

Single Entry: entry data is added to CSV

Multiple Entries: CSV data is blank.

EDIT: Found out via some research that the full path is not necessary for SelectNodes and that by changing the PS Script to `$responses = $parsedXML.SelectNodes("//Response")` I am now able to gather the data for all entries, but they are not separated by an underscore (Example 2 would come out as 04/19/201904/26/2019). I have adjusted the question accordingly.

Comment: try `-Value (($responses | Where-Object {$_.Label -eq $GCValue} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value) -join '_')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question, don't even know if I should just remove the post entirely. This is the adjustment I made to the relevant piece of PS code above:

`$objMarry | Add-Member -Type noteProperty`

`-Name $GCValue`

`-Value ($responses | Where-Object {$_.Label -eq $GCValue} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value` **| Foreach-Object {$_ + '_'})**
        `}`

From there, to remove any underscores at the end of each CSV column I added a pipe during the creation of the CSV to replace any instances of underscores followed by commas with just commas (see code snippet below)

```
    $csvobject | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | %{$_ -join ','}| % {$_.Replace('"','')} | %{$_.Replace('_,',',')} | Out-File $CompletedCSV
```

Don't know if this is the most eloquent way to accomplish this, but it works.